# Using deferred.promise.then with try & catch

Tags: angularjs, deferred

I am working on this function where I get data from the server, iterate through it, add a new field `color`. In some cases when the user is moving between pages before they load we use `deferred.cancel('User aborted.');` to cancel the requests made.

The issue I am facing is when that happens I get the JS error `Cannot create property 'color' on string 'U'`, so in order to prevent it from happening without having to add in if conditions to verify the data (I'm trying to add in something generic so if something goes wrong I just want to throw a warning) I added in a `.catch(function(response){})` to catch the exceptions, that didn't stop the JS error from coming up though.

Here's the code for that part:

```
deferred.promise
.then(
    function(data) {
      console.log('loadClassTimetable - data', data);
      // Calculating Percentages
      angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
        var percentage = parseInt(value.number_active_students, 10) / parseInt(value.number_total_students, 10);
        console.log("Percentage - ", percentage);
        if (percentage == 0 || isNaN(percentage)) {
          data[key].color = '#BBC6CE';
        } else if (percentage >= 0.75) {
          data[key].color = '#11202d';
        } else if (percentage >= 0.5) {
          data[key].color = '#324f67';
        } else if (percentage >= 0.25) {
          data[key].color = '#486175';
        } else {
          // Less thant 0.25
          data[key].color = '#8297a9';
        }

      });

      // Getting classes and adding events AFTER setting the colours
      var classes = ClassManager.getAllClasses();
      parseEventnAdd(classes, data);

    }, angular.noop)
  .catch(function(response) {
    console.warn("Exception caught in loadClassTimetable", response);
  })
  .finally(function() {
    $scope.loading = false;
  });
```

Any thoughts on the best way to resolve this? Do I have to add in conditions to verify that the data is in the structure I expect it to be or can I have something generic in?

Comment: what kinda data are you getting from the resolved promise?

Comment: Consider using the JavaScript `try` and `catch` blocks. For more infomation, see [MDN JavaScript Language Reference - try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch).